# Can't seem to make OneGet/Chocolatey work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-packagemanagement

I got pretty excited about OneGet. But I can't get it to work.
I followed the instructions here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AptGetForWindowsOneGetAndChocolateyOnWindows10.aspx .
Basicaly, what I get is that I do install-package vlc (or git, or totalcmd, etc...), and the command seemingly successfully runs, but vlc does not seem to be installed on the computer. I get some ~4kb files in the c:\chocolatey directory, none of them seems to be an actual executable.

I did the following in a PowerShell:

```
get-provider chocolatey
install-package git
install-package totalcmd
install-package vlc
```

(it went nice, asked are you sure? type questions, I said 'Y' to each one, showed progress bar for downloading first chocolatey, then nuget, then the necessary packages)

```
PS C:\Chocolatey> tree /f
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 00000085 0684:49C7
C:.
└───lib
    ├───git.2.6.2
    │       git.2.6.2.nupkg
    │
    ├───git.install.2.6.2
    │   │   git.install.2.6.2.nupkg
    │   │
    │   └───tools
    │           chocolateyInstall.ps1
    │
    ├───totalcmd.0.1.0.20120702
    │   │   totalcmd.0.1.0.20120702.nupkg
    │   │
    │   └───tools
    │           chocolateyInstall.ps1
    │
    └───vlc.2.2.1.20150630
        │   vlc.2.2.1.20150630.nupkg
        │
        └───tools
                chocolateyInstall.ps1
```

I tried running powershell as administrator, it does not work either.
What do I do wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Still sad that there was no error message whatsoever.

Comment: wow i wish that step was included in the online examples